# Getting 3 new entries in /dev/ttyUSBx for each 3G dongle connected

Tags: usb, power, usb-hub

I am trying to connect 4 3G dongles to Raspberry Pi B+, I have some troubles making them all reply to AT commands, and I see that each time I connect one dongle, 3 new /dev/ttyUSBx ports are created in /dev

Is this normal ? Shouldn't I see just one port there? I feel that I am reaching some limitations when I have 4 dongles and 12 ports there. Only 3 unique devices reply to AT commands.

I connected them trough a 4 port hub.

The lsusb -t output:

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
```

Comment: Please provide a model number for the dongle. It's probably providing multiple endpoints for various functions.

Answer (score 1):

Linux supports having a very large number of tty devices in /dev/ (each time you open another xterm or tmux window tty devices are created, ever left a laptop running and ended up with 100s of xterm windows across multiple workspaces?). USB (and the linux USB implementation) also supports a fairly large number of connected devices. I would assume the reason you are having issues with the 4th modem is because the hub can't supply enough power to 4 modems at once (3g modems use a lot of power).

Comment: Yes, I think it was a power issue, it worked eventually but power led blinks (indicating low power). I used ports 0,3,6,9, but I am curious why 3 exact ports for each one GSM dongle.